# Envió de email automatico en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo mi proyecto laravel en un servidor compartido, necesito realizar un envío de mail diario con información de las facturas emitidas por los clientes, he estado viendo tutoriales sobre cronjobs-laravel y Schedule he logrado completar uno de ellos.

https://medium.com/@cvallejo/cronjobs-laravel-585017b32862 mi pregunta es, como programar desde el servidor este envio de mail, porque si uso 
**php artisan schedule:run** laravel busca las tareas pendientes y las ejecuta pero una sola vez.

No tengo acceso ssh por lo que me pregunto como puedo hacer sin esto, en uno de los tutoriales el instructor hacer uso de 
**crontab -e**
 y luego 
*** * * * * php /ruta-al-proyecto/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1**
pero estos no los reconoce como comando interno, alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a cpanel para configurar el servidor compartido? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ9p62mWN_E https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwpUjz1tMbA Si solo tienes acceso por ftp, no vas a poder programar la ejecución de cron como me comentas. Ya que se tendría que asociar a una url y no se podría programar su ejecución. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, gracias por la pronta respuesta, no tengo acceso, solo me dan acceso ftp que se podría hacer en mi caso? me preguntaba si habría forma de hacerlo con un llamado artisan tal como se hace en  $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');

Comment: En ese caso, habla con tu proveedor de hosting, y pídeles que agreguen el cronjob, muchas veces no tienen problema con hacerlo. Luego tu te manejas con schedule.

Comment: mmm eso podría ser pero, una cosa que quisiera saber, si reinician el servidor el cronjob se iniciara solo? o alguien debe estar al pendiente de hacerlo? es una cosa que me preocupa